# Calculating max time in four different columns in R

Tags: r, time

Using R in a dataframe I have four columns of time format that I want to calculate the max time of each row. In some cases there are NAs in random cells. I used apply(X,1,max) but it didn't work. I then tried to replace the NAs with X[is.na(x)]<-0 but it was not successful as well. Can anyone help  me with those two issues?

[image: a sample of the dataframe can be seen in this image]

Comment: Please don't post data as images. or in .[NORM format](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Take a look at [how to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Do you want `apply(df, 1, max, na.rm = TRUE)` ?

Answer (score 2):

How about adding the column directly with tidyverse and pmax?

Example below:

```
library(tidyverse) 
Date1 = c(as.Date('2020-01-01'), as.Date('2020-05-06'), NA, NA, NA)
Date2 = c(as.Date('2020-07-06'), as.Date('2020-03-06'), NA, NA, NA)
Date3 = c(as.Date('2020-08-06'), NA, NA, NA, as.Date('2020-03-06'))
df = data.frame(Date1 = Date1, Date2 = Date2, Date3 = Date3)

df %>% 
  mutate(maxdate = pmax(Date1, Date2, Date3, na.rm = TRUE))

Date1         Date2      Date3       maxdate
2020-01-01   2020-07-06  2020-08-06  2020-08-06
2020-05-06   2020-03-06  <NA>        2020-05-06
   <NA>       <NA>       <NA>        <NA>
   <NA>       <NA>       <NA>        <NA>
   <NA>      <NA>        2020-03-06  2020-03-06
```